# va_start warns " second parameter of 'va_start ' not last named argument"

Tags: c, function, variables, gcc, warnings

The code works perfectly but gcc and clang reports a problem on the va_start

stackoverflow says for me write something more but I really don't know what =)

```
int Matrix_cool_input (matrix *A, ... )
{
    int num = A->m * A->n;

    va_list arguments;
    va_start (arguments, num);

    int i,j;
    int rc = 0;
    double v;

    for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
    {
        i = x / A->m;
        j = x % A->n;
        v = va_arg ( arguments, double );
        rc |= Matrix_set(A,i,j, v);
    }
    va_end(arguments);
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: `A` is the last named argument before the variadic `...` decl. why are you passing 'num', a local automatic variable? See [**`va_start`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start) for how it *should* be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be

```
va_start (arguments, A);
```

pass the last named parameter as the second argument of `va_start` macro.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page of `va_start()`

> void va_start(va_list ap, last);
>
> #### va_start()
>
> The va_start() macro initializes ap for subsequent use by va_arg() and va_end(), and must be called first.
>   The argument last is the name of the last argument before the variable argument list, that is, the last argument of which the calling function knows the type.

so, `va_start()` is *supposed* to work with the `name of the last argument before the variable argument list`, which is `A`. You're not supposed to pass any other value [e.g, function local `num` as per your case] to it.